# Angular 2 ngSwitchCase, OR operator not working

Tags: angular, switch-statement, ng-switch, or-operator

I have multiple switch statement but for some case i need the common case. So, i am trying the

`OR operator => ||`

Example:

```
        <ng-container [ngSwitch]="options">
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'a'">Code A</ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'b'">Code B</ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'c'">Code C</ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'d' || 'e' || 'f'">Common Code</ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>Code Default</ng-container>
        </ng-container>
```

**Output:**

```
if case = 'd' returns Common Code
else if case = 'e' and 'f' returns the Code Default
```

Here the second last case consists of multiple cases, and now by default the `case 'd'` is only working and not working for `case 'e' and 'f'`.

I can't see any multiple case inside the `ngSwitchCase` docs:

> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitchCase-directive.html
>   https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html

**Doesn't Angular 2 supports the `||` operator in the `ngSwitchCase`?**

Answer (score 136, accepted):

If you evaluate `'d' || 'e' || 'f'` the result is `'d'` and when `options` is not `'d'`, then it doesn't match. You can't use `ngSwitchCase` that way.

This would work:

```
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="true">
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="options === 'a'">Code A</ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="options === 'b'">Code B</ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="options === 'c'">Code C</ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="options === 'd' || options === 'e' || options === 'f'">Common Code</ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>Code Default</ng-container>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: Wow! you are `Angular God` :D I was not thinking that the `[ngSwitch]` should have the true condition. ;) Thanks for the way out of this. I was scratching my head for hours.

Comment: Thanks, you're welcome. Glad to hear it fixes your issue :)

Comment: Works!  Key point: [ngSwitch]="true" will allow all "SwitchCase condition" tags to be evaluated

Comment: I think it's better to use *ngIf in that case rather than hacking ngSwitch. less code, more readability

Comment: @Mihail 
I also thought that until I realized that the default case was even more complicated to put

Comment: @ObjectiveTC in fact it says match a 'true' value, then he evaluate until he found a true, and if he don't he will fall in the 'ngSwitchDefault'

Comment: @DanielTorresLaserna - you are right.  Thank you for the correction.

Comment: but according to JS/TS language definition, it should not be `true`, it should be chosen `'key'` itself. Angular-guys went a different way :/

Comment: I use `ngSwitch` when I want to evaluate a statement once, instead of using `ngIf` multiple times. In that case, your solution won't work!

Answer (score 36):

I think this syntax is better:

```
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="options">
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'a'">Code A</ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'b'">Code B</ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'c'">Code C</ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="['d', 'e', 'f'].includes(options) ? options : !options">Common Code</ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>Code Default</ng-container>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: Very nice solution

Comment: Maybe better *ngSwitchCase="['d', 'e', 'f'].includes(options) && options"

Comment: @MinaDjuric Your code in `ngSwitchCase` returns a boolean (true/false) value, but the `options` value type is a string. So this code will not work.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks Bahador R, helped me create a pipe.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'switchMultiCase'
})
export class SwitchMultiCasePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(cases: any[], switchOption: any): any {
        return cases.includes(switchOption) ? switchOption : !switchOption;
    }

}
```

use as

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="switchOption">
...
<div *ngSwitchCase="['somecase', 'anothercase'] | switchMultiCase:switchOption">
```